# How do I update tokens in a JSON file using Rest API C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, dalsoft.restclient

Browserstack.com have a REST API that stores the results of Automated test sessions in a JSON file. 
By default it sets the *status* token to "done" but you can update using the REST API e.g. "passed" or "failed". 
It requires Basic authorization using your username & password.
They give an example of how to do this but it's a bit messy. So I wanted a simpler way of updating the file and only the tokens I was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using DalSoft's *RestClient* application:

```
public static async Task DalSoft(string SessionID, string TestStatus)
{
  string Uri = "https://www.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/" + SessionID +    
  ".json";

  string AuthToken = "Basic " +  
  Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));

  dynamic client = new DalSoft.RestClient.RestClient(Uri);

  var status = new { status=TestStatus };

  var result = await client
      .Headers(new { Authorization = AuthToken })
      .Patch(status);

      string Myresults = result.ToString();
}
```

https://github.com/DalSoft/DalSoft.RestClient/issues/40#issuecomment-334219145